# How to monitor AWS health endpoint from Azure application insights

Tags: azure, alert, azure-application-insights

I would like to monitor the AWS health endpoints for connect and health services from Azure.
How can we achieve this ?
Any suggestions please

We would like to alert on any errors received from AWS health endpoints from Azure.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor AWS health endpoints and receive alerts on any errors from Azure, you can set up a monitoring and alerting solution using Azure Monitor. It allows you to collect and analyze data from various sources like including external endpoints and set up alerts based on specific conditions
for more info go through this documentation

[Azure moniter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview)